# How is NASM able to allocate so memory per label

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am novice in assembly.I have questions.

```
code: db 1111
```

How does the code can contain this number if we allocate only one byte? As I know one byte can contain max. 255 number no more.
And the second question

```
variable: dw 100
```

How is it stored in memory ? I know the most 64 bit architecture use one byte per address.How does one address can specify on two address?(As I know there are 16 bit per word in nasm because it’s arrangement).

Thank you and sorry if this question is very stupid.

Comment: My NASM warns me about that (`warning: byte data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions are not stupid, but rather involve some essential topics:

1. The declaration `code: db 1111` can mean different things:

   1. The value `1111` can be of decimal or hexadecimal type, or something else (like octal) - making it *invalid*.
   2. The value `1111` can be of binary type which equals 15 decimal and therefore it'd fit into one BYTE. This is the most likely way that this declaration is accepted.

   Usually the type is indicated by a prefix (like `0x...` for hexadecimal in **C**) or suffix (like `1111b` with `b` for binary), but here it isn't... I don't know if you can set/change the default numbering format in NASM, but without an affix, the expression is *invalid*/*doesn't fit into one BYTE*.
2. The declaration `variable: dw 100` does reserve two BYTEs in memory. The first byte is stored at the address you access and use as a reference, and the second BYTE of the WORD is stored at the address+1. So a WORD does really occupy 2 BYTEs. Which 8-bit part of the 16-bit value is stored at which location is set by a concept called [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). On an x86/x64 computer, the order is *Little-endian*.

Comment: FWIW: nasm [doesn't support setting a default base for numbers](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/blob/5368e4579403daaf6c12165eb857893f8acfc7f8/nasmlib/readnum.c#L68) but constants that don't fit in their reserved space are allowed with the emission of a warning. Only the lower bytes are used (so `db 1111` turns into `db 0x57` since 1111 is 0x457)

Comment: This is a NASM question;  It truncates numbers that don't fit, same as for `add al, 12345`, and warns, as shown on https://godbolt.org/z/531Krjf55.  If you're going to talk about possibilities like other default bases, best to introduce that by saying what *other* assemblers might do.

Comment: (2) and a WORD load from `[variable]` will get *both* bytes, including the zero in the high byte.  We still say that the word's address is where it starts, even though it spans more than one address.  Think of addresses / labels as attaching / applying to the start of something, not to the middle of a byte.